# C# ПОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ самый быстрый POST запрос на полученный GET в JSON

Tags: c#, json, post, get, производительность

Всем привет, нужен очень быстрый запрос и моментальный ответ так чтобы запрос прилетал быстрее всех) Сейчас появился конкурент, он отправляет запросы с огромной скоростью, так что мне остаётся только то что он выбросил =( Уже и весь код распаралелил, вообще никак не пробьюсь, и рдпшки максимально близко к хосту берём,(пока не прям рядом) (нужны сейшелы/сейчас германия) всё равно полный фарш, и никак не конкурирую =(((
Вопрос, как максимально быстро пульнуть ответ после получения нужного параметра, может я json долго перебираю или post запрос криво написал, как можно ускорить сие творение? Что я делаю не так? Или всё таки нужно еще ближе подходить к хосту?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;


namespace Test
{
   class Program
   {
       static async Task Main(string[] args)
       {
          
         
     
           string Token1 = "Токен 1";
           string Token2 = "Токен 2";
          
          
           using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All });
           client.DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20;
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://site.com/api/");
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Token1);
       
           using var client2 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All });
           client2.DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20;
           client2.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://site.com/api/");
           client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Token2);
          

           string exchange_idFIND = "";
           string PriceFind = "";
          
          
           while (true)
           {
               Parallel.For(1, 2000, GET);
           }
          
         
          
           async void GET(int n)
           {
               HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("getExchangeOrders/").Result;
               string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               if (result != "{\"Your request limit 200/minute has been reached\"}")
               {
                   JObject myObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

                   Parallel.ForEach(myObj["orders"], resource =>
                   {
                       string  direction = resource["direction"].ToString();
                       string exchange_id = resource["exchange_id"].ToString();
                       string price = resource["rub_amount"].ToString();
                       if (direction == "Нужный параметр")
                       {
                           exchange_idFIND = exchange_id;
                           PriceFind = price;
                           Parallel.For(1, 200, POST);
                       }

                   }
            
                   );
                  
               }
 async void POST(int n)
           {

               var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "exchange_id", exchange_idFIND } };
               var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
               var response2 = await client2.PostAsync("setOrder/", content);
               var responseString = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               if (responseString != "{\"Your request limit 200/minute has been reached\"}")
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(responseString + ""+ PriceFind);
               }
           }
             

           }




       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Возьмите, да через хотяб `Stopwatch` замерьте каждый конкретный этап вашей программы, поймете, где узкое место, поймете, что именно тут стоит править. Может у вас просто банально слабое соединение, которое требует много времени, может ведь такое быть? Может, тогда что ваш код с этим сможет сделать? А ничего. А так, по коду, я вам советую не про скорость думать, а про хотяб базовые вещи по типу `Task` нормальных, разделения всего на методы, и прочее, ибо сейчас у вас каша, а не код, с кучей костылей по типу `async void`.

Comment: Через Stopwatch замерял соединение, весь этап идёт 0.06 секунды, а вот POST идет 0.17-0.2 секунды. async void добавил потому что это распараллеленный асинхронный процесс, может где лишний добавил, мне IDE сам предложил, распараллелил прогу первый раз вообще. Вроде работает, причем быстро, но не достаточно где именно потерял нужную миллисекунду понять не могу(

Comment: Тоесть в этом и вопрос, как максимально быстро ответить серверу

Comment: 1. В чем отличие от предыдущего вопроса? Добили бы тогда его. 2. Указанно время соединения для вас много? Если да, то идите тогда улучшайте соединение, а не код. Если нет, то, где тесты других участков? 3. `async void` не должно вообще быть в вашем коде, как, по сути, и `Parallel.For()`. Почитайте про асинхронное программирование, про `Task`, как их запускать пачкой, как их ограничивать, как дожидаться и так далее.  Вот вы нам дали код, который тесно завязан на конкретном сервере и хотите, чтоб мы его улучшили. Как мы это можем сделать без всей информации? Мы даже не знаем, что для вас норма.

Comment: Отличие, там было про Get запрос ответ, но суть в том что нужно POST. 
Уточню вопрос, может есть более быстрый перебор Json или пульнуть POST ответ, загвоздка где то тут=(
Слишком долго отвечаю серверу=( 
Да я по образованию не программист, я простой электрик, и я всё учусь сам методом проб и ошибок, до этих пор всё работало=( Сейчас я неделю пытаюсь понять что не так в моём POST и перебором JSON =( Пробоемма где то тут

Comment: `Get` и `Post` это одинаковая кухня, что, если потребуется `PUT` или `DELETE` будете под каждый вопрос делать новый? В любом случае, я вам уже сказал, что надо делать - каждый участок кода протестируйте по времени, сколько занимает то или иное действие, а потом уже на основе этих данных и смотрите, что у вас занимает больше всего. Вангую, что покажет вам просто долгую отправку данных из-за соединения, а это уже дело не в коде, а в вашем соединении, провайдере, расстоянии.

Comment: Почитайте эту дискуссию. Пост в принципе медленнее даже сам по себе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211881/why-is-the-get-method-faster-than-post-in-http